# Configuring Spring MVC and Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc

We have an existing Spring application (not web) and wish now to expose some REST endpoints to it's functionality. The requirement is also for an embedded Tomcat.

While for a strategic solution we would like to move to Spring Boot, in the short term we will be implementing the endpoints using Spring MVC.

I have created a demo Spring Boot project and used that to figure out the correct dependency versions for Spring and Tomcat.These are:

```
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core-5.23
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el-.5.23
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23
org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.23
org.springframework:spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-test-4.1.0.RELEASE
```

In our main project, have added code to instantiate and start Tomcat, and this appears to be successful, as indicated by the console:

```
Nov 14, 2017 2:32:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
```

The main class which, which is a `@Service` run the application now implements `WebApplicationInitializer`. The `onStartup` method has been implemented:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.company.xxx");
    return context;
}
```

The controller has been implemented as follows:

```
@RestController
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Test";
    }

}
```

However, the `onStart()` method in the main class is not getting called, even though it is a Spring bean and is being injected with it's correct dependencies. When sending a get request (http://localhost:8090/) Tomcat returns 404 - Not Found.
Can anyone advice what is missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Configuration class?  Where is the Spring Component Scan configured?

Comment: There is class with these annotations which is registered with the context after it has been instantiated, context.register(Config.class)

Comment: Ok. Good.  Some people have also indicated that if they don't have the spring-context-support they do not see the onStartup method being called.  Can you check your dependencies and make sure it is being included?

Comment: Added it, but it does not appear to help